# No module named 'lib.mouse' - python

Tags: python, pip

I installed the library Mouse in a virtual environment through the conda prompt, and while importing the lib.mouse library, results in an error.

```py
import argparse
import datetime
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
from lib.mouse import Mouse
from lib.video_source import getVideoSource
from lib.polygon import drawQuadrilateral
from lib.user_interaction import getPerpectiveCoordinates
from lib.fgbg_calculations import getThresholdedFrame
from lib.heatmap import Heatmap
from lib.coordinate_transform import windowToFieldCoordinates
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d5f001ef6688> in <module>
      5 import cv2
      6 import numpy as np
----> 7 from lib.mouse import Mouse
      8 from lib.video_source import getVideoSource
      9 from lib.polygon import drawQuadrilateral

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.mouse'
```

Comment: Do you have the virtual environment active at the time of the import?

Comment: yes. conda activate opencv-env

Comment: "No module named 'lib.mouse'" -- and what exactly does that have to do with OpenCV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you copy your code from https://github.com/dev-labs-bg/football-stats

In the repo, there is a folder called *lib*. **You need to copy that too**. It's not part of opencv library, it's a python module from that repo.